# How to Trigger In-Cell dropdown list in Excel Cell on Alt + Down Arrow by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2007. I have coded a userform which functions like Excel 2010 Autofilter dropdown and assigned <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> shortcut for this userform load macro. Now I am trying to show the In-Cell dropdown aka the default drop in a cell instead the userform if the cell is not in autofilter range like below.

```
Sub AUTOFILTEREXCEL2010VERSION()
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
  Load AutoFilterfrm
  AutoFilterfrm.Show
Else
  'Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}", "" 'Tried this alternative also
  Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}"
  'Application.SendKeys "%{DOWN}" 'Tried this alternative also
  SendKeys "%{DOWN}"
  Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}", "AUTOFILTEREXCEL2010VERSION"
End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks to [Kamlesh Kishor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6473755/kamlesh-kishor) for the image.

The problem is the above code does not display the in-Cell dropdown list like the above image i.e. if `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode` is False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> is the same as right click into a cell and selecting *"Pick from drop-down list..."*. This context menu button is assigned to the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>.

So instead of removing and reapplying the shortcut and going with a crappy `SendKeys` that comes with a lot of issues, just do the following and run the context menu directly:

```
Public Sub AUTOFILTEREXCEL2010VERSION()
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        Load AutoFilterfrm
        AutoFilterfrm.Show
    Else
        Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(ID:=1966).Execute 'execute the kontext menu item
        Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}", "AUTOFILTEREXCEL2010VERSION"
    End If
End Sub
```

Instead of using the ID:=1966 of the menu item (which makes it work in different languages) you could also use

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Pic&k From Drop-down List…").Execute
```

but that would only work for english Excel versions then.

---

Note the difference between thow 2 lines below:

```
Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}"      ' re-assigns the shortcut to its original
Application.OnKey "%{DOWN}", ""  ' removes the shortcut completely (does nothing anymore)
```